# How to Repack a Flutter Plugins to use for Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-plugin, flutter-provider

for this specific case, I'm trying to use Provider on Flutter Web,

but I'm sure  that this will not be the last flutter package

that I will use on flutter web, so I'm trying to understand

how to solve this as a generic situation.

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589163/using-flutter-mobile-packages-in-flutter-web) :

> Using flutter mobile packages in flutter web

and this answer:

> you can also use libraries that are referencing Flutter framework that was repackaged for flutter_web. Like provider was forked [[link]](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/82). You only can't use plugins atm.

For my understanding the suggested procedure is

1. **Fork**
2. **Repack**
3. **Import**

While "Fork" is straight forward, feel the need to ask:

- **How to Repack a Flutter Plugins to use for Flutter Web?**

since this time I got lucky and **[Kevin](https://github.com/kevmoo/provider)** already did the repacking

- How do I import it? [edit: [nevermind...](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/82#issuecomment-495277633) ]

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you don't want to make it public, i think you can just copy the source code (lib folder) over to your project and change the name space of the imports - i know that isn't your question, but might get you on your way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534998/error-when-adding-provider-package-to-flutter-web-project)

just

- clone the repository you want to use,
- copy the files in your project
- fix the errors

then everything should work